# How to find all Discord Invites in a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-re

How to find all Discord Server Invites in a message. I have asked a similar question before but it doesn't work for me somehow. So I came up here. I can find nothing more about this in the Internet. The "re" package could possibly work but what is the regex?

```
import re

inviteregex = re.compile(r'discord(.gg|.com/invite)/.{3,10}')
links = re.findall(inviteregex, 'here is the link discord.gg/gpDcZfF')
print(links)
```

Expected Comeout:

```
['discord.gg/gpDcZfF']
```

But the result is:

```
['.gg']
```

Comment: What is regex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression (PS: you could at least google it) Also please add the code that you tried so far, what are the results, what are the expected results, errors/tracebacks...

Comment: just edited the message, no error. Also I know what is Regex. But I am not sure that the one I used here is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for an invite is the next one:

```py
(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?
```

Applied to the `on_message` event

```py
async def on_message(message):
    invite_regex = re.compile("(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?")
    result = invite_regex.findall(message.content)

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a regex, which can identify invites from dsc.gg and discord.io

```
(https|http)://(dsc\.gg|discord\.gg|discord\.io|dsc\.lol)/?[\S]+/?
```

https://regex101.com/r/qUsc7J/1